# Replacing in data frame by character

Tags: r

If I replace some values with a character by `data[data<0] <- "Down"` and after that by : `data[data>0] <- "Up"` I get all the values to "Up", but if I inverse the substitution I get it work the way I like.

```
data<-runif(30, min=-5, max=5)
data[data<0]<-"Down"
data[data>0]<-"Up"
#[1] "up" "up" "up" "up" "up" "up" "up" "up" "up" "up" "up" "up" "up" "up" "up"
#[16] "up" "up" "up" "up" "up" "up" "up" "up" "up" "up" "up" "up" "up" "up" "up"
```

but if I do this I get a correct result:

```
data<-runif(30, min=-5, max=5)
data[data>0]<-"Up"
data[data<0]<-"Down"
#[1] "down" "up"   "up"   "down" "down" "down" "down" "down" "down" "down"
#[11] "down" "down" "up"   "down" "down" "down" "up"   "up"   "down" "up"  
#[21] "up"   "down" "up"   "up"   "down" "down" "up"   "up"   "down" "down"
```

The solution is simple, do the second one, but I am curious why this happens. At first I thought it was something involved with the conversion to character but, it can not be that because then changing the sequence will not affect or it would affect the same way.
Any idea?

Comment: Try doing `"Down" > 0` - it should show you what's going on

Comment: And why it reads the text as a factor or integer?
    `>"Down" > 0
    [1] TRUE
    >str("Down")
    chr "Down"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to avoid conversion to character, and do the 2 tests simultaneously:

```
ifelse(data>0,"Up","Down")
```

**EDIT**

To explain what's happen , strangely R use the sign **"-"** to check if a character is negative or positive.

```
"-a" < 0
[1] TRUE
```

So when you do in this order (> then <) you keep the sign and it works.

**EDIT**
"-" is ordered before "0" in ASCII  . Here a function that can accept an ascii character and return the decimal value:

```
asc <- function(x) { strtoi(charToRaw(x),16L) }
> asc("0")
[1] 48
> asc("-")
[1] 45
```

Comment: I just assumed that the best way to replace was this way and I didn't consider other options. But this is easier to avoid this kind of problems, thanks.

Comment: @Llopis it is dangerous to rely on order!

Comment: R does not use the `-` sign to check if a character is negative or positive.

Comment: @hadley Ok. But what does R do to get TRUE with `"-a" < 0`?

Comment: "-" is ordered before "0" in ASCII

Answer (score 2):

A vector in R can only hold values of one type. The vector was originally created with numeric values.

In your first bit of code (`data[data<0]<-"Down"`) your assignment converted the vector mode from numeric to character. The remaining numbers in the vector were changed from numeric mode to character mode. At the end of that assignment, the vector looks something like ...

```
 [1] "Down"              "4.50482521206141"  "Down"             
 [4] "Down"              "Down"              "Down"             
 [7] "3.81024733651429"  "1.01603321265429"  "Down"             
[10] "3.30486473860219"  "4.82019837480038"  "1.3452106853947"  
[13] "2.02783531043679"  "Down"              "Down"             
[16] "Down"              "Down"              "Down"             
[19] "4.59091864991933"  "Down"              "2.09894138388336" 
[22] "Down"              "0.638334625400603" "1.58013242762536" 
[25] "2.14735288871452"  "Down"              "1.67530178790912" 
[28] "4.91423513041809"  "Down"              "1.71986542874947"
```

When it comes to the second comparison - an implicit type conversion occurs. R wont let you compare numbers and strings. So the number 0 is converted to the string "0". (ie. `data[data>0]` was coerced to `data[data>"0"]`)

Which is why it did not work as you thought it should. (All of the strings those with the value "down" and those with a number as a string all test TRUE to being greater than the string "0".)

In the second example, the numeric strings begin with a "-", which in character encoding is less than the character encoding for "0".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I thought it would just skip the string ones